# Dividing a string into 2 arrays as ucwords and lowercase

Tags: php, regex

I have several sentences that includes people names (or just surnames) and the rest of the string. I am trying to separate them as person's name and the rest. (The sentence always starts with name)

```
$string = "John Doe loves to eat apples";

$string = "John loves likes to run";

$string = "John Mike Doe loves to swim";

$string = "Greg McDermott lives in Sydney"; // this from comments is a good scenario.
```

And my array outcome should be

```
[ "John Doe", 'loves to eat apples" ]
[ "John", 'likes to run" ]
[ "John Mike Doe", 'loves to swim" ]
```

I achieved something with `preg_match_all()`, but I was wondering if there is a more direct way to achieve it.

```
$string = "John Doe loves to eat apples";
preg_match_all('/((?:^|[A-Z])[a-z]+)/', $string, $matches);
$person = implode(' ', $matches[0]);
$rest = str_replace("$person ", '', $string);
```

Comment: What if input is `Greg McDermott lives in Sydney`?

Comment: @anubhava: Good scenario Anubhav.

Comment: If your names are always followed by loves or likes https://3v4l.org/fVsR3

Comment: @anumhava - Good scenario indeed. Then the name should be `Greg McDermott` - @fourth-bird no the text is unpredictable

Comment: So what follows the names does not matter or should it be either loves, lives or likes?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, that's right - Just separate person name and the rest is what I want to achieve. Given answer handled my cases with str_replace (McDermott case too). If you have a better solution, I'd be happy to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture the name that is present in the start of string whose identification is that each of the first name or last name will start with a capital letter.

```
^[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\b(?: \b[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\b)*
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `\b[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\b` - This captures the Name which should start with a capital letter. `\b` ensures it doesn't do a partial match.
- `(?: \b[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\b)*` - This accommodates any further surnames present after the first name zero or more times.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RLW4ke/2)**

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)